# Comparing a new Object() with another new Object() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've created two new Objects:

```
var a = new Object();
var b = new Object();
```

and after comparing, I have got those results:

```js
var a = new Object();
var b = new Object();
console.log(a == b); //false
console.log(a > b); //false
console.log(b > a); //false
console.log(a >= b); //true
console.log(b >= a); //true
```

Please explain how this happens?

Comment: iirc, objects are stored by reference, so it's basically looking at the address of the object in memory.

Comment: @JeremyJackson: No, it isn't.

Comment: The inequality comparisons you are doing are comparing the string `[object Object]` with itself, because such comparisons coerce the operands to a string in this case. Those strings are not greater than or less than each other, but they are greater than or equal to or less than or equal to.

Comment: They are not the same object(==) , but the same type (<,>,<=,>=) ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Object references compared with `==` or `!=` (or `===` or `!==`) are compared based on whether they refer to the **same object**. If so, they're equal; if not, they're not equal.

But the relational comparison operators (`>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=`) don't compare the references, they coerce their operands to something they *can* compare: Numbers or strings.

In the case of `new Object()`, that coercion ends up creating a *string*: `"[object Object]"`. And of course, `"[object Object]" >= "[object Object]"` is true because they're equal.

So *in effect*, what you're actually doing is:

```
console.log(a == b);                 //false
console.log(String(a) > String(b));  //false
console.log(String(b) > String(a));  //false
console.log(String(a) >= String(b)); //true
console.log(String(b) >= String(a)); //true
```

...but note that other object types coerce differently, because objects can choose how they coerce in this situation (where the spec prefers a number over a string) by implementing/overriding `valueOf`. For instance, `Date` objects coerce to a number when you apply a relational operator to them if the other operand can also coerce to number. So you can reliably use `dt1 > dt2` to see if `dt1` represents a date/time after `dt2` — but you **can't** use `dt1 == dt2` to check if `dt1` and `dt2` (two separate `Date` objects) have the same date/time in them, because `==` will check to see if they're the same object instead. Which leads us to this bit of amusement:

```js
var dt1 = new Date(2016, 5, 23);
var dt2 = new Date(2016, 5, 23);
console.log(dt1 < dt2);  // false
console.log(dt1 > dt2);  // false
console.log(dt1 == dt2); // false!
```

All the gory details can be found in the specification:

- [Relational operators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-relational-operators)
- [The algorithm they use](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-relational-comparison)
- [How various things get converted to primitives](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive)
- [`Object`'s `toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: LOL it's not meant that way, no, but I see what you mean. :-)

Comment: Another fun comparison with same reason: 
null == 0 is false, null > 0 is false but null >= 0 is true

Comment: I like JS, but looking at the date == comparison being false makes me bang my head on the table...

Comment: @gpinkas: Yeah. I was joking with a friend about that, saying "Maybe it would have been better to have 'is' and 'isnot' operators for comparing object references, and leaving == and != for value comparisons. But you know we'd just get people asking "Why is '1 is 1' false?" ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The behavior is entirely as defined in the [ECMAScript standards](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0).

1. `a == b` is `false` because they do not refer to the same object, as defined in [the **Abstract Equality Comparison** section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison):

   > 3. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
   >
   >    a. Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.

   [The **Strict Equality Comparison** algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) itself specifies, after all other types have been checked:

   > 8. If x and y are the same Object value, return true.
   > 9. Return false.
2. `a < b` is `false` because [the **abstract relational comparison** algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) first converts the operands to non-Object types via the [**ToPrimitive** abstract operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive) (which in the case of Objects results in a string representation of `"[object Object]"`).

   Since both operands will convert to the same string value, they will be equal to each other.
3. `a <= b` is `true` because `b < a` is `false`, as per the old definition of [the **Less-than-or-equal Operator** ( <= )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.3).

   > 5. Let r be the result of performing abstract relational comparison rval < lval with LeftFirst equal to false. (see 11.8.5).
   > 6. If r is true or undefined, return false. Otherwise, return true.

   Again, the abstract relational comparison operation will convert the operands into string representations `"[object Object]"` which will be equal to each other, so that the `b < a` comparison will evaluate to `false`:

Comment: 2 is wrong. `r` is only `undefined` if one of the values is `NaN` which is not the case here (both are converted to strings per http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8).

Comment: What do you think `Let px be the result of calling ToPrimitive(x, hint Number).` does? This converts `x` to either a number or a string. In case of "plain" objects wit will be a string because `valueOf` doesn't return a primitive (see link in my previous comment).

Comment: @Thriggle: Look at what [`ToPrimitive`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) does, and then look at the beginning of Step 3: *"If it is not the case that both `Type(px)` is `String` and `Type(py)` is `String`, then..."* `ToPrimitive(new Object())` returns a string. (Those links are to the 5.1 spec to be consistent with the comments above, but it is of course outdated now. Easier to read, but outdated. :-) )

Comment: The hint that is passed to `ToPrimitive` is not an enforcement. It just means "please give me a number if possible". The only effect is that it calls `valueOf` before `toString`. But `valueOf` simply returns the object itself in this case. OTOH, `Date` objects overwrite `valueOf` to return a number, which is why relational comparisons works for `Date` objects out of the box.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! I'll update my answer to use the newer spec... I always fall into the trap of clicking the (old) links from MDN instead of just going out there myself.